# Javascript and Performance

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I'm experiencing a weird issue here. I have a Javascript code which scrolls my page diagonally. It takes the scrollTop() value and divides it to scroll diagonally. But when i try  to scroll it with two "layers", the foreground scrolling more than the background layer, i experience a sluggish animation when i finish scrolling to bottom and try to scroll to top again.

I have tried somethings as i saw here, like caching vars, declaring in e.g. $(window) as $window with no luck. I dont know if this issue its happening by the Math or Animate.

Here's my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sPB3a/

You can experience it in fullscreen here: http://jsfiddle.net/sPB3a/show/

Thanks for any tip!

Comment: The reason it slows scrolling is because you are running the function inside `$(window).scroll()` once for every pixel the scroll bar moves. If you scroll the entire page, that means the function is being called 3325 times - in a matter of a second or so.

Comment: How well does it work for you if you disable animations?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yes I agree, though Chrome deals with it better than Firefox.  Also, a much bigger problem is that the layout is quite wrong in Firefox; many of the titles are partially cut off.

Comment: If i disable animations it works, but not as expeted. I know im doing a lot of calcs in a matter of sec. But like i said, if i disable the foreground layer, it works pretty smooth.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript Animate Performance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10760988/javascript-animate-performance)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the root cause of the problem is the size of the background images. I removed all background images from your page and i get a perfectly smooth scrolling.

They are really heavy. You should try with very low quality jpg images (less that 20k). If this works, you have then to work on the images to find the good compromise.

Note: png format is a looseless image format. It's good for small images and screenshots (where large areas have exactly the same color). It's not good when there are a lot of very similar colors, blurs and gradients. e.g. photos. In your case, you should use jpg format and ajust the quality level.

Answer (score 0):

You are querying dom in your `$(window).scroll` function. I dont think its a good practise.

Cache your variables, accessing dom via javascript is very slow.

I've a lot of things in your code, do check if it helps you.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DTHfP/2/)

```
$(function(){


    var $window = $(window);
    var windowHeight = $window.height();
    var windowWidth = $window.width();
    var content = $("#content");
    var section = content.children("section");
    var sectionsNumbers = section.length-1;
    var illusion =  $(".illusion1");
    var mask = $('#mask');
    // Scroll sets

    var windowScrollX = ((sectionsNumbers+1)*windowWidth)-windowWidth;
    var windowScrollY = ((sectionsNumbers+1)*windowHeight)-windowHeight;

    content.css({"width":windowScrollX+windowWidth,"height":windowScrollY+windowHeight});

    illusion .css({"width":windowScrollX+windowWidth,"height":windowScrollY+windowHeight});


    // Set mask w and h

    mask.css({"width":windowWidth,"height":windowHeight});
    $(".scrollRule").css("height", (sectionsNumbers+1)*windowHeight);


    section.each(function(sectionCount,val) {

        // Defines its width and height
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.css({"width":windowWidth,"height":windowHeight,"left":sectionCount*windowWidth,"top":sectionCount*windowHeight});


    });

    // When window scrolls


    var angleVar = windowScrollX/windowScrollY;
    var curScrollTop;
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        curScrollTop = $this.scrollTop();
        content.stop().animate({left: "-"+curScrollTop*angleVar, top: "-"+curScrollTop}, {duration: 1250, easing: 'easeOutQuart'});
       illusion.stop().animate({left: "-"+curScrollTop*angleVar*0.5, top: "-"+curScrollTop*0.5}, {duration: 1250, easing: 'easeOutQuart'});        
    }); 

});
```